# Make facet_matrix show density plot for variable with missing values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a facet_matrix showing scatter plots and autodensity plots on the diagonal. However, for some reason it does not show the density plot for a certain variable (`gini_eurostat`). I assume this is because there are some missing values for `gini_eurostat`. How can I make it show the density plot, even though there are some missing values?

This is the code I used:

```
    ggplot(df_Q2, aes(x = .panel_x, y = .panel_y)) + 
  geom_autodensity() +
  geom_point(alpha = 1, shape = 16, size = 0.5) + 
  facet_matrix(vars(c(intraEU_trade_bymemberstate_pct, gini_eurostat, exports_currentUSD)), 
               layer.upper = 2, layer.diag=1, layer.lower = 2) +
  theme_few()
```

The data frame looks like this:

```
head(df_Q2[,c("intraEU_trade_bymemberstate_pct", "gini_eurostat", "exports_currentUSD")])
# A tibble: 6 × 3
# intraEU_trade_bymemberstate_pct gini_eurostat exports_currentUSD
#                        <dbl>         <dbl>              <dbl>
# 1                             8.6          NA         96701496330.
# 2                             8.8          27.4      116638893905.
# 3                             8.8          25.8      141025428359.
# 4                             8.4          26.3      153625979356.
# 5                             8            25.3      170827273868.
# 6                             8.1          26.2      204299603066.
```